# customize error message of throw exception javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception

I am trying to customize error message for exception throw in javascript.

So far my attempts have been failed.

I am trying this but its not working

```
  function abc(sender, args) {
    alert("ex2");
    throw ("error new"); 
    alert("");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `throw` and `object` (with **name** and **message** properties) instead of a `string` to generate a custom `exception`:

```
function abc(sender, args) {
  alert('ex2');

  throw {
    name: 'YourErrorName',
    message: 'YourErrorMessage'
  }; 

  alert('');
}
```

Here is a sample of how to raise the event and catch the `exception` which contains your name and message values:

```
function triggerError(){
  throw {
    name: 'YourErrorName',
    message: 'YourErrorMessage'
  }; 
};

(function cathError(){
  try {
    triggerError();
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e.message);
    console.log(e.name);
  }
}());
```

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/bNqBvr) to see it working.

Comment: what code? I already posted my code there's nothing more to it

Comment: @fali I think that you are misunderstanding the usage of throw and exceptions, check the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with this simple code:

```
throw new Error("Something terrible has happened");
```

When you simply throw a string, you lose functionality such as the error stack.  Somewhere up the call stack you might want to do something like:

```
catch(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
    alert(err.message);
}
```