# Error throw for date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to throw error on validation of date, 
Date cannot be older than current date, if empty has current date as valid from date.

I have tried this:-

```
var olddate = new Date("Fri Sep 22 2016");


var currentdate = new Date();

if(olddate > currentdate)
{
document.write("date is older than curent date");
//how to throw error here
}

else if( olddate ==null || olddate =="")
{
document.write("date is null or empty");
//how to throw error here
}

else
{


document.write(currentdate);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [customize error message of throw exception javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935497/customize-error-message-of-throw-exception-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) using the constructor `new Error("Date is null or empty.")`, where you can pass the error message as a parameter. Then you can throw it as `throw err`.

```js
var olddate = new Date("Fri Sep 29 2018");
var currentdate = new Date();

if (olddate > currentdate) {
  document.write("date is older than curent date");
  
  var err = new Error("Date is older than curent date.");
  throw err;
} else if (olddate == null || olddate == "") {
  document.write("date is null or empty");
  
  var err = new Error("Date is null or empty.");
  throw err;
} else {
  document.write(currentdate);
}
```